# Drupal best practice for complex relationships

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm designing a **Drupal 7 website where nodes/entites have complex relationships** (1-many, many-to-many). For example:

```
Student (registered user) can belong to one ore more classes
Student can take one or more exams each semester
Teacher will take a note about each student in his class after each semester
```

My main concern is about:

1. Performance: queries should be fast and simple when rendering pages
2. Relationship: need to have two way relationship ( => can list related content based on content or vise versa)
3. Views Integration: should be fieldable and easy to list related content in [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)

*==> I come up with 2 solutions:*

**Method 1: the Drupal way**
I know that there are some modules like EntityReference, Field Collection,... but don't know how to use, mix them the right way. Let's say how to create content type for a class, it's fields that link to user table and then easy to show the list of students on a given class?

===> The question is: **What is the best practice for my case and what modules I should use and mixing together to solve this problem**. What content type, it's field, and relationship I should create?

**Method 2: could be not the Drupal way**

Normally, I will design some tables in 3rd normal form ([3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)) for those entities and their relationship: student, teacher, class, exam...I mean that this approach **could be not the Drupal way** as normal with field_xxx magical tables for each field of an custom content type, right? Hereunder are example of them:

```
Student table ( uid, name, full_name, other meta data columns) , of course the uid is foreign key point to Drupal user table
Class table (id, name, code_name,...)
Student_Class junction table (student_id, class_id, semester_id)
etc,.....
```

===> The question is: **If I do it this way, is there any module which support to auto generated create CRUD forms, or API to create form to manipulate those tables, easy to allow field-able with Views module.**

Please correct me for any misunderstanding and your ideas are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Err should this be on [drupal.SE]?

Answer (score 1):

The Drupal way with Entity Reference, Views, Field Collection (I would add [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form), [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations), [Views Megarow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_megarow)) is, in my opinion, the good one : you will be able to create back-office (and front end) screens very (I mean *very*) quickly using Views, related content (using Entity Reference) can be fetched both way, Inline Entity Form allows you to set up creation forms containing the related entity creation form (so create an entity and its related entity at the same time). [Drupal Commerce](https://drupalcommerce.org/) is a good example of what you can do with these modules (see this [entity relationship model](https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/products)). [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) can help to set up your business logic. So points 1 & 2 are (can be), in my humble opinion, satisfied with the Drupal way.

**BUT...**

This flexibility comes at the cost of complex requests, and eventually bad performance. You'll find all over the web posts about how Drupal is slow, and when you start playing around with a complex setup, it can be a serious problem. But with a good server configuration (cache, proxy...) and no PHP in Views :), it can be done (I run several Drupal Commerce sites, with a good server and a good sysadmin it's ok).

And you'll have to dive into Drupal logic, Views logic, Rules logic, which can be frustrating at some points : something you would code in a few PHP lines will take you a lot of clicks in Drupal interface. Of course, for tricky things, you can always build a small custom module doing just what you need.

About the second solution, I have no experience to share on Drupal and custom data model, but I guess you should consider applications frameworks (Symfony, Zend, CakePHP...) if you want to be free for the DB design.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks @Flo. I can come up with the 2nd solution because it looks easier for me compare to the Drupal way, but I think it also quite tricky. Here what I suppose to do: Move the CRUD to subdomain with other app framework. Let's say `my.com` is my main Drupal site. => `my.com/class/note` -> will show all notes of the current logged-in user, etc. And the `custombe.my.com` => all the CRUD, manipulate biz logic based on `other framework (Yii)` will go here => **what could be a better way for me? How do we solve the different domain problem** Thanks

Comment: You can have Yii on a custombe.my.com and Drupal on my.com, you just have to configure your Apache vhosts accordingly. Then I guess you have to share your database : https://www.drupal.org/project/data allows you to display foreign tables with Views. Displaying Drupal data in Yii can be more difficult due to Drupal complex database schema. But why do you want to keep Drupal in the loop ? Why don't you stick to Yii only ?

Comment: Thanks @Flo: I have to keep Drupal because it looks like there are so many things needed to be done with Yii2 from the beginning to match the features that I already had with Drupal (core +  my custom modules)